# Copying string using strncpy cause garbage value in output

Tags: c

I have a file name "test.mf" as a character pointer. I want to change extension of this file into "test.pfb". I am writing a simple code for this but it is resulting in printing some garbage characters. Running same code on online C compiler results in no garbage values but running it using GCC results in garbage value. 
If I can achieve the same thing (changing file extension of .mf file to .pfb) in a much better, fast way please suggest. I am new in this so please ignore silly mistakes.

Code

```
char *Get_PFB_font_file_name(char *TTF_Font_name) 
{
    size_t alen = strlen(TTF_Font_name);
    alen = alen+1; 
    char mystring[alen];
    const char* extension = ".pfb";
    char *PFB_File= malloc(alen+1);
    strncpy(mystring, TTF_Font_name, alen-4);
    strcat( mystring, extension );
    strncpy(PFB_File, mystring, alen);

    if(!PFB_File)
    {
        printf("error in get TTX conversion function");
        exit(1);
    } 
    return PFB_File;
}

int main ( void )
{
    char *MF_Font_file_name = "test.mf";
    char *PFB_Font_file_name;
    PFB_Font_file_name = Get_PFB_font_file_name(MF_Font_file_name);
    printf("PFB font file name is %s \n", PFB_Font_file_name); // garbage value here (test�.p)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(mystring, TTF_Font_name, alen-4);`: that doesn't nul-terminate right?

Comment: @EdHeal it's to be sure that the C++ compiler isn't used :)

Comment: [The `strncpy` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) might not terminate the string in one case. And that happens for you.

Comment: And then `strcat` goes *WTF?* so add `mystring[alen-4] = 0;` after your first call to `strncpy` before `strcat` (and you will want to insure `mystring` is again *nul-terminated* after `strncpy(PFB_File, mystring, alen);`

Comment: you forgot the null termination of string

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks i have fixed it by adding a null termination. Can u suggest me if this is the right way to achieve what i want or can i improve it by some other way?

Comment: @EdHeal What's wrong with `new`? Should we really care about keywords from any language we don't use? If this will break the code in C++, that's a nice bonus.

Comment: @Gerhardh - It is a keyword for C++ and other languages - so may lead to confusion. Also it is not a meaningful variable name

Comment: @EdHeal There are lots of keywords in other languages which are also not relevant for C. If it forces the reader to think a few seconds, that's not a bad thing. It reminds them that it is not C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

about [`strncpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

> The strncpy() function is similar (to strcpy), except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

```
strncpy(mystring, TTF_Font_name, alen-4);
strcat( mystring, extension );
```

this has undefined behaviour because `TTF_Font_name` is longer than `alen-4` so the warning/limitation above applies, and `strcat` cannot compute the size of `mystring` properly.

One way to fix it: just insert this between the two lines:

```
mystring[alen-4] = '\0';
```

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan:  sorry conflicting edits. But semicolon added thanks.

Comment: I tried that but same garbage value. I have a similar function in same file which almost uses same variable names. can it be the cause of it?

Comment: Thanks it worked. Do you think it is the right way to do what i want to achieve can i improve this?

Comment: there's a way to use `printf` to limit the size but the formatting must be passed as literal, so in your case it's not very convenient. Handling strings is C is very manual, close to the asm level. Of course, using C++ would improve string handling (now that you renamed `new` :)) Seriously, I suggest that you create a small set of tested functions to handle those extension replacements. Once tested & robust, you can use them everywhere in your project(s), instead of copying pasting some buggy code around.

Comment: also, make sure you're allocating enough bytes for your dest string. It seems OK but a bit complicated (with your many +1s). If you don't want to be bothered, use a big auto buffer like `char buf[1000];`, and use `strdup` in the end.

Comment: ahh fine. Thanks alot. Actually i was trying to avoid creating a buffer (giving a manual size) but thats an alternate. As far as +1's are concerned actually as u noticed extensions may be 3 characters or 2 like "mf" and "pfb" in that case it varies so i had to do it manually.

Comment: Don't skimp on buffer sizes. Sure, be reasonable, but I would a lot rather have a buffer that is 1000 bytes too long, than one that is 1-byte too short `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin specially on auto memory, when allocation is done with a single addition. OK maybe 1000 is too much but shaving it too close like you're on a 8-bit 1980 machine is as stupid.

Comment: Yes, I agree. If I was sure the max was 30 chars, 64 or 128 would be reasonable. If I wanted to be 100% (or as close as possible safe), I would use `PATH_MAX` -- which with gcc gives a whopping 8192 bytes `:)`